# Cannot set a static ip in Solaris(OpenIndiana)

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, static-ip, ifconfig

I am running this command:

```
ifconfig e1000g0 192.168.0.1
```

I have done over 50 variations with unplumbing/plumbing, up/down, netmask, and broadcast. Doesn't matter cause `ifconfig e1000g0` always shows my ip address as 0.0.0.0.

I need to get this set up so I can test my crossover network and get down to the root cause of why zfs is only delivering a fourth of the speed I have benchmarked the server at.

Probably useful info, I have two nics on the box and have been running all these commands over the second through ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you disable AutoMagic with:

```
svcadm disable network/physical:nwam
svcadm enable network/physical:default
```

You should be able to configure anything you want manually then, like:

```
ifconfig e1000g0 plumb
ifconfig e1000g0 192.168.0.1/24 broadcast + up
```

You'll probably also want a default gateway:

```
route add default 192.168.0.254
```

Replace IPs as necessary for your network.

Comment: The automagic thing fixed it. Unfortunately no change in ZFS read or write speeds onto another area. Thanks.

Comment: ZFS is a local file system, what would it have to do with r/w speeds across the network?

Comment: I have slow speeds(40MB/s) over SMB and NFS(using the zfs set command). Was seeing if my switch was causing problems. I guess I forgot to put a comma after 'write speeds' in my second sentence; now that I have eliminated my networking equipment as the culprit for my slow speeds, and a test this morning confirmed this with max GigE speeds over FTP on my normal network settings, I am moving onto why SMB and NFS protocols are slow.

Comment: Running NFS over UDP usually improves speeds drastically for small file/blocksize operations. Might also be the NIC, I know some implement polling which *can* noticeable improve speed.